# How to selectively consume message from Tibco queue

Tags: java, spring-jms, tibco-ems

I have two applications which send a JMS event to another system and the response message will be picked up by Message consumers in both applications. But they need to ignore the message if its not meant to their application.

I can pass some identifier to the external system which they can send it back. But how do i configure selective listening?

I am using Spring DMLC container for listening

Answer (score 2):

Set a header and use a [selector expression](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.html#setMessageSelector-java.lang.String-).

e.g. `myHeader='foo'`

As the javadoc says, see the JMS Spec for complete syntax.